# VS 2013 MVC 4.5 broken references

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, reference, nuget-package-restore

I have a MVC 4.5 C# project in Visual Studio 2013. It was running perfectly without any errors, until a co-worker started to work with me.

My co-worker's VS version was 2015, and when he synced (via TFS) with my project looks like all my references got broken. Now VS doesn't recognize my Razor tags anymore, and gives me tons of errors and warnings.

Depending on the number of files I open the list of errors and warning get bigger. Here is an example of what it looks like when I open just the main view of the project:

```
Warning 101 Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

Warning 103 Unknown element 'lmweb_mvc.models.leaseviewmodel' or element cannot be placed here.

Error   104 The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Error   105 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   106 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   107 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition 
for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a 
using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   108 The name 'FormMethod' does not exist in the current context

Error   109 No overload for method 'DropDownList' takes 1 arguments

Error   110 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   111 The name 'FormMethod' does not exist in the current context

Error   112 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   113 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   114 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   115 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   116 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   117 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   118 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   119 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   120 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   121 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   122 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   123 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   124 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   125 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   126 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   127 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   128 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   129 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   130 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   131 The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Error   132 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition 
for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   133 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   134 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   135 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   136 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   137 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   138 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition 
for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   139 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   140 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   141 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   142 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Whey you say 'synced', what do you mean? Are you using a version control system (e.g. Git, TFS)?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution? Also, you can try deleting your .suo file.

Comment: @newmanth I meant TFS synchronization. Yes, I'm using version control and I tried to roll back but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: Just to be clear, did the other developer do a check in? If so, you can run a diff between changesets.

Comment: And a random thought: MVC is dependent on NuGet packages, so first reading this, I suspected it had something to do with package restore. What are yours (and your teammate's) NuGet settings (Tools | NuGet Package Manager | Package Manager Settings)?

Comment: @SteveGreene I tried both and none of them worked. Thanks for the tip though, I didn't know about the suo file

Comment: @newmanth my teammate isn't working on the project anymore. In my NuGet Package settings I have all boxes checked under both General and Package Sources. Not sure if that is what you want to know

Answer (score 0):

If you use NuGet I suggest you to make a

```
Update-Package –reinstall
```

Else you can take a look reference Path to see what's wrong